# Using & in URL causes XML error: The reference to entity "foo" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: jsf, entity, facelets, ampersand

I'm trying to get google map image with the following code:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{profile.latitude},#{profile.longitude}&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false"/>
```

but I get exception in my browser which says:

> Error Parsing /content/profile.xhtml:
>   Error Traced [line: 48] The reference to entity "zoom" must end with the ';' delimiter.

How can I avoid interpreting `&` in URL as XML?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace `&` with `&amp;` as the markup is being parsed as XML and `&zoom` is being parsed as an HTML entity which does not exist in XML.